# Custom order action success message

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Everytime I fire my custom action an success message "Order updated" is displayed.

Is there a way to hide this message after firing custom order action? For example if my action do not process?

```
function _custom_order_action_process( $order ) {

    // some code
    // some code
    // some code

    if ( ! $valid1 ) {
         // Oooops...
         return;
    }
    if ( ! $valid2 ) {
         return;
    }

    //here we go...

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_custom_order_action','_custom_order_action_process' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is change the message value.
we can use `redirect_post_location` for that.

```
function _custom_order_action_process( $order ) {

    // some code
    // some code
    // some code

    if ( ! $valid1 ) {
         // Oooops...

         add_filter( 'redirect_post_location', 'redirect_post_location', 99 );
    }
    if ( ! $valid2 ) {

         add_filter( 'redirect_post_location', 'redirect_post_location', 99 );

    }

    //here we go...

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_custom_order_action','_custom_order_action_process' );


function redirect_post_location( $location ) {
    remove_filter( 'redirect_post_location', __FUNCTION__, 99 ); // remove this filter so it will only work with your validations.
    $location = add_query_arg('message', 99, $location); // 99 is empty message, it will not show. Or if by any chance it has a message, you change to higher number.
    return $location;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But I'm not sure how it works. Theses "query args" are variables to wordpress process on POST requests? Is that right?